# Is it possible for a regression to have the right functional form but still suffer from omitted variable bias?

Tags: regression, econometrics, bias

Suppose that
$$ Y = b + aX + e$$
where you know that $E[Y|X] = b + aX$.  Is it true that the model cannot suffer from omitted variable bias?  If this is true, then it follows that omitted variable bias can always be considered as a funcional form bias (namely, changing the functional form $f(X)$ will remove the bias.)

Here is a proof of why I think this is true.  Since $b + aX = E[Y|X]$, we have that
  $$ E[e|X] = E[Y-b-aX|X]= E[Y - E[Y|X] |X] = E[Y|X]  - E[E[Y|X] |X] = E[Y|X] - E[Y|X] = 0.$$

Therefore, $e$ and $X$ are not correlated and there is not omitted variable bias.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not I agree, but to be more sure I need to know what you mean by "functional form": (1) simply that the effect of $X$ on $Y$ is linear (i.e. that $Y= b + aX + e$ for *some* values of $b$ and $a$)? Or do you mean that (2) $Y= b + aX + e$ for *specific* (fixed) values of $b$ and $a$. Because if you mean the later then sure, but if you mean the former, then no way.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, Alexis.  I mean, we have a loss function $L(Y,f(X)) = (Y-f(X))^2$, and we want to find $f(X)$ that minimizes the expected loss $E((Y-f(X)^2)^2]$.  In this case, the solution is $f(X) = E[Y|X]$.  We are trying to estimate this function.

Comment: I realize the question is not well writen, I am sorry.  The point is that if we start by imposing the model $Y = b + aX$, we can have an omitted variable bias.  Hence, we try to find a $Z$ to add to the model to remove this bias, ie., we pass to the model $Y = b + aX + cZ$.  My point is that the problem is not omitted variable bias, but wrong functional specification because if we pass to $Y = E[Y|X] = f(X)$ then $f(X)$ and the error term are not correlated anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your explanation in the comment. See, for example, the first diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox), which relates to omitted variable bias. What is it you're proposing to do to eliminate the problem?

Comment: @Glen_b:In Wikipedia's graph, looking at the residual vs. fitted plot would suggest that the assumed functional form of the model is not okay. Thus, some forms of omitted variables bias and wrong model structure can both be detected using similar methods. Maybe this is the basis of the question.

Comment: @MichaelMayer I'm not having any difficulty understanding what the plot would show. I'm really looking for the OP to clarify the question in light of an illustrated example of the problem.

Comment: @Glen_b: I am quite convinced that you are understanding Wiki's plot ;). Just trying to help user3487 to clarify his question.

Answer (score 2):

Adding or deleting variables in the RHS of the equation is automatically a "change of the functional form", of *any* function, not just in the case of a stochastic specification. After all a function is determined by its domain and its functional form. So I don't see what we gain by "realizing" that this is so. By definition, if the functional form is "right", there are no omitted variables.

Moreover, the situation can be more complex. The specification may suffer from omitted variables *misspecification*, but *not* from ommited variable *bias*. This happens when the omitted regressor(s), which may be causally linked and useful in explaining the variability of the dependent variable, is/are mean-independent of the included regressor(s).

In such a case, the correct specification is

$$Y = b + aX + cZ + e$$

but still

$$E[b + aX + cZ + e\mid X] = b + aX + cE[Z\mid X] + E[e\mid X] = b + aX =  E[b + aX +  e\mid X]$$

since $E[Z\mid X]=0$, due to mean independence. This has the consequence that the estimator of the coefficient $a$ won't suffer from "omitted variable bias", but the estimated equation as a whole will be a sub-optimal predictor of the dependent variable.

So, the answer to the title question is "No", with the extension that the question "Is it possible for a regression to have the *wrong* functional form but *not* suffer from omitted variable bias?" is answered in the affirmative.